# NoSuchElementException when trying to call kb.nextInt()

Tags: java

Quick question. Still fairly new to Java and my test class is giving me this error.

```
Please enter length of tail: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at LeftArrow.drawHere(LeftArrow.java:18)
at ArrowTest.main(ArrowTest.java:75)
```

Here is the code for the test class

```
public class ArrowTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RightArrow right = new RightArrow();
        LeftArrow left = new LeftArrow();

        System.out.println("RightArrow Class: Calling drawHere()");
        right.drawHere();

        System.out.println("LeftArrow Class: Calling drawHere()");
        left.drawHere();                  //Error pointing to this line
                                          // (at ArrowTest.main(ArrowTest.java:75))
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the RightArrow and LeftArrow classes, just the relevant code. I commented the lines that the error was referring to.

```
 public class RightArrow extends ShapeBase
 {
     public void drawHere()
    {
        int lengthTail, widthHead;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter length of tail: ");
        lengthTail = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter an odd numbered width of arrowhead: ");
        widthHead = kb.nextInt();
    }


   public class LeftArrow extends ShapeBase
 {
     public void drawHere()
    {
        int lengthTail, widthHead;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter length of tail: ");
        lengthTail = kb.nextInt(); //Error pointing to this line at LeftArrow.drawHere(LeftArrow.java:18)
        System.out.print("Please enter an odd numbered width of arrowhead: ");
        widthHead = kb.nextInt();
    }
```

I commented out the right.drawHere() in the test class and it seemed to work okay. So I am fairly convinced it is because I am calling the same method from two classes derived from the same abstract class. Is there a way that I can fix this? Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I found that if I don't close the kb from the first arrow class called upon it does not throw this error. I can only assume its because of me closing System.in which is why it's causing a problem. Can anyone explain to me why making another instance of Scanner(System.in) doesn't just re-"open" System.in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling the `nextInt` method, you can use the `hasNextInt()` method on the scanner object to check if there is a value to get, which can be used to avoid exception. Try this:

```
if (kb.hasNextInt()){
    lengthTail = kb.nextInt();
}
```

In your case, I think you are not providing enough inputs, which could lead to `NoSuchInputException`.
Have a look at [the Scanner class doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Scanner object where while you calling `right.drawHere()` there you initialized the Scanner kb with `System.in` this will buffer through all data available in `System.in` left it empty for future use therefore it is throwing NoSuchElementException in `left.drawHere()`.

**Solution:**

Make `Scanner` object `kb` as static and accessible for both `LeftArrow` and `RightArrow`